# DSolve can not solve a second order ODE!

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a second-order ODE but at first, I get this error:
[image]

It seems mathematica cannot understand R is just a constant. But the problem is, even after removing the range DSolve can not solve the equation:
[image]

Is there any way I could solve this ODE!?

Thank you already for your time :)

Comment: It is hard to copy code from an image. Better to post plain text code to make it easier. Did you try from clean Kernel? May be you have some funny characters used,? Your double primes looks strange for me. They should be straight upticks, yours are tilted to the right. With `DSolve` you do not need to specify the limit of the independent variable. This is only needed for `NDSolve`

Comment: Do you think that all nonlinear 2nd-order ODEs have an analytic solution?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: The ODE is invariant under scaling $\{h\to h k,\ z\to k z\}$, so theoretically there's a first integral that can be constructed. Knowing where the ODE comes from might help....

Answer (score 2):

There is no analytical solution for this. Maple gives a solution but its solutions depends on solving a first order ode which is not solvable.

So your best bet is series solution.

Btw, `DSolve` gives an error when doing

```
ClearAll[y, x, r]
DSolve[y'[x] == x, y[x], {x, 0, r}]
```

The `r` above must be a numerical value and not a symbol.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[y'[x] == x, y[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, with `DSolve` giving range of the independent variable is not needed. You only need to do this with `NDSolve`.

```
DSolve[y'[x] == x, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see, the same solution is given.

For your ode, you can solve it using series. But expansion point can not be zero. Any other expansion point will work. Here is solution with 3 terms.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
numer= ((-2+d)*z+(d-1)*h[z]*h'[z])*(1+h'[z]^2)
denom=z*h[z]*(1-h'[z]+h'[z]^2);
ode=h''[z]==numer/denom
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode,h[z],{z,1,3}]  (*do not use 0*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For reference, here is the solution given by Maple

```
restart;
num:= ((-2+d)*z+(d-1)*h(z)*diff(h(z),z))*(1+diff(h(z),z)^2):
den:=z*h(z)*(1-diff(h(z),z)+diff(h(z),z)^2):
ode:=diff(h(z),z$2)=num/den;
```

[image]

```
dsolve(ode)
```

[image]

In plain text, the above is

```
h(z) = ODESolStruc(_a*exp(Int(_b(_a),_a)+c__1),[{diff(_b(_a),_a) = -_b(_a)^2*((
_a^4*d-_a^4+2*_a^2*d-3*_a^2+d-2)*_b(_a)^3+(3*_a^3*d-4*_a^3+_a^2+3*_a*d-6*_a)*_b
(_a)^2+(3*_a^2*d-5*_a^2+_a+d-2)*_b(_a)+_a*d-2*_a)/_a/(1+(_a^2-_a+1)*_b(_a)^2+(2
*_a-1)*_b(_a))}, {_a = h(z)/z, _b(_a) = z/(diff(h(z),z)*z-h(z))}, {z = exp(Int(
_b(_a),_a)+c__1), h(z) = _a*exp(Int(_b(_a),_a)+c__1)}])
```

Notice `ODESolStruc` above. This means no analytical solution. [ODESolStruc](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve%2FODESolStruc)  is similar to Mathematica's `DifferentialRoot`, which means it is not solved analytically.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This equation has a solution mentioned in [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02319). I have checked and the answer is correct but I still have no idea how we can get that from mathematical! I guess there are assumptions I am missing.

Comment: @NK92 may be you could post that solution in your question, either as latex or as Mathematica code or if not possible, at least as an image. I am not going to read the paper looking for it myself.